# I need help making JButtons disappear when a condition is met (and also adding buttons when a condition is met)

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jpanel, jbutton

Nothing appears to be wrong with this from what I have seen

Code for Driver:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class rpsDriver{

public static void main(String[] args){


//jpanel stuff

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors Game");
  frame.setSize(1280,720);
  frame.setLocation(250, 50);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setContentPane(new rpsPanel());
  frame.setVisible(true);



}//end main

}//end class
```

The problem I have is that when I run the code and me or the computer gets to 3 wins the end screen that says you win/lose appears but the rock, paper, scissors button on the left is still there (and I would like for it to disappear). Also, I would like to add buttons below the thing that says you win/lose that will let you restart the game (making userScore, tieScore, and compScore = 0), and a button that ends the game (closes the panel and ends the run). I'd appreciate any help.

Code for the JPanel (the one I have problem with):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class rpsPanel extends JPanel{

Random rand = new Random();

//variables used in code
String compChoice = "";
int userNum; //number that corresponds to a choice
int compNum; //number that corresponds to a choice
int num;
int score; //score to decide who wins
String result = "";
String userChoice = "";
//win and tie count
int userScore = 0;
int compScore = 0;
int tieScore = 0;


//boolean variables for each choice
static JFrame frame;
boolean rock = false;
boolean paper = false;
boolean scissors = false;



public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

setLayout(null);
//background
//     setLayout(new BoxLayout());
ImageIcon wooden = new ImageIcon("woodenBG.jpg");
g.drawImage(wooden.getImage(), 0, 0, 1280, 720, null);
g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("VS" , 630, 385);
  
//images for rock,paper, scissors
ImageIcon rockChoice = new ImageIcon("rock.png");
ImageIcon paperChoice = new ImageIcon("paper.jpg");
ImageIcon scissorsChoice = new ImageIcon("scissors.jpg");
  
/*displays the choice the user made*/
if (rock){   
g.drawImage(rockChoice.getImage(), 350, 300, 200, 200, null);
}
else if (paper){      
g.drawImage(paperChoice.getImage(), 350, 300, 200, 200, null);
}
else if (scissors){      
g.drawImage(scissorsChoice.getImage(), 350, 300, 200, 200, null);
}
/**********************************/
  
       
  
/* computer makes choice after user */
if(rock || paper || scissors){
num = rand.nextInt(9);
     
     if(num == 1 || num == 4 || num == 7){ //rock choice
        compChoice = "rock";
        compNum = 1;
        g.drawImage(rockChoice.getImage(), 800, 300, 200, 200, null);
     }
     else if (num == 2 || num == 5 || num == 8){//paper choice
        compChoice = "paper";
        compNum = 2;
        g.drawImage(paperChoice.getImage(), 800, 300, 200, 200, null);
     }
     else if(num == 3 || num == 6 || num == 0){//scissors choice
        compChoice = "scissors";
        compNum = 3;
        g.drawImage(scissorsChoice.getImage(), 800, 300, 200, 200, null);
     }
  }
  /**********************************/
  
  /*the logic part to decide the winner*/
  score = userNum - compNum;
  if(score == -2 || score == 1){
     result = "win";
     userScore++;
  }
        
  if(score == 2 || score == -1){
     result = "loss";
     compScore++;
  }
        
  if ((score == 0) && (rock || paper || scissors)){
     result = "tie";
     tieScore++;
  }
  /***************************************/
  
  
  //Displays the outcome
  g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawString("The outcome: " + result, 425, 100); 
  
  
  //This shows the score of you and the computer
  g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawString("Your score is " + userScore, 25, 50);

  g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawString("The computer's score is " + compScore, 925, 50);
  
  g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawString("The amount of ties that occured are " + tieScore, 400, 50);
  
  //user wins the game after user wins 3 rounds
  if(userScore >= 3){
     g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150));
     g.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);
     g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 75));
     g.setColor(new Color(57, 255, 20));
     g.drawString("You WIN!", 300, 330);
     
  
  }
  
  //computer wins the game after computer wins 3 rounds
  if(compScore >= 3){
     g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150));
     g.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);
     g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 75));
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.drawString("You LOSE! Try again", 400, 330);
  
  }

   }//ends the paintcomponent class

   public rpsPanel(){      
   setLayout(null);
  
  
  //images for rock, paper, scissors
  Icon rPic = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("rock.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
  Icon pPic = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("paper.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
  Icon sPic = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("scissors.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
  
  
  /* buttons for rock paper scissors */
  JButton rockBTN = new JButton(rPic); //rock button
  rockBTN.addActionListener(new rockListener());
  rockBTN.setBounds(20, 200, 70, 70);
  add(rockBTN);

  JButton paperBTN = new JButton(pPic); //paper button
  paperBTN.addActionListener(new paperListener());
  paperBTN.setBounds(20, 300, 70, 70);
  add(paperBTN);
  
  JButton scissorsBTN = new JButton(sPic); //scissors button
  scissorsBTN.addActionListener(new scissorsListener());
  scissorsBTN.setBounds(20, 400, 70, 70);
  add(scissorsBTN);
       
  /*************************************/
  
  
  
  
  /* Creates the buttons to restart or end the game when one team has 3 wins */
  
  JButton restartBTN = new JButton("RESTART");
  restartBTN.addActionListener(new restartListener());
  
  JButton endGameBTN = new JButton("END");
  endGameBTN.addActionListener(new endGameListener());
  endGameBTN.setBounds(300,500,50,50);
  
  /*****************************************************/
 
 if(userScore < 3 || compScore < 3){
     rockBTN.setVisible(true);
     paperBTN.setVisible(true);
     scissorsBTN.setVisible(true);
     restartBTN.setVisible(false);
     endGameBTN.setVisible(false);
  }
  else if (userScore >= 3 || compScore >= 3){
     rockBTN.setVisible(false);
     paperBTN.setVisible(false);
     scissorsBTN.setVisible(false);
     restartBTN.setVisible(true);
     endGameBTN.setVisible(true);
     
  }
  
  }

   /* listeners for each button */ 
  private class rockListener implements ActionListener{  //rock  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     //repaints game with the rock choice
     rock = true;
     repaint();
     revalidate();
     paper = false;
     scissors = false;
     userNum = 1;
     
    
     
  }  
   }

  private class paperListener implements ActionListener{ //paper
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        
     //repaints game with the paper choice
     paper = true;
     repaint();
     revalidate();
     rock = false;
     scissors = false;
     userNum = 2;
  }
   }

   private class scissorsListener implements ActionListener{//scissors
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     //repaints game with the scissors choice
     scissors = true;
     repaint();
     revalidate();
     paper = false;
     rock = false;
     userNum = 3;
  }
   }

   private class restartListener implements ActionListener{//restartBTN
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  //if button is clicked it will restart game with score at 0
  
  }
   }

   private class endGameListener implements ActionListener{//restartBTN
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  //if button is clicked it will end the game, remove panel, and end the run
  
  }
   }


  
  /**********************************************/  
 }//ends rpsPanel
```

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  A `CardLayout` allows you to switch from one JPanel to another.

Comment: Don't repost questions. Keep all the information in one place so everybody knows what has been suggested.